# Styling Contact Form 7 Radio Buttons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, radio-button, contact-form-7

I'm trying to style radio buttons generated by the Contact Form 7 plugin for WordPress. All the examples I've seen have relied on having a label with a `for=""` parameter on them like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="this-button" name="test-button">
<label for="this-button">Click Me</label>
```

But the buttons generated by CF7 don't allow you to add that `for=""` parameter. It looks like this on the page:

```
<label>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yes-button" value="Yes">
</label>
```

I still need to have custom radio buttons, but is there another way to do it that doesn't rely on the `for=""` parameter? jQuery is being loaded on the page already, so I can use a jQuery solution.

Any help would be great, I've tried several solutions with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

I installed "[Checkator](https://github.com/QODIO/checkator)", then added this:

```
//Add "checkator" class
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".my-page label > input").addClass("checkator");
});
```

...at the top of `fm.checkator.jquery.js` to add the "checkator" CSS class to the radio buttons.

Manually applying the CSS class to the radio buttons allowed Checkator to find them, and from there I was able to style them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a class to one of the radio buttons similar to:

```
   <label class="container">One
   <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
   </label>
```

You should be able to add custom classes even through wordpress or get a CSS plugin to let you add custom CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp is a great resource.

-Robert

Comment: I have actually tried that tutorial. That method will not work without me modifying the CF7 plugin code.

Comment: Do you have a link to your website/page you want to modify?

Comment: No, I don't, it's only local currently. I can copy snippets of the code if that would help.